# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView that is already populated with a select button to view the selected item.

But once the method is called I get this below message, I can seem to figure it out

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

This is suppose to select `Dim cusName As String = Report.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text` in index 0

Here is sample of my table

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" CssClass="Tab" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="100%">
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="tsaTabPanel" runat="server" HeaderText="Report" EnableViewState="False">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" ID="RCReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="id"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="customerName" HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="customerName" ></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="customerEmail" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="customerEmail"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="fee" HeaderText="Fee" SortExpression="fee"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" />   
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
        </cc1:TabContainer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind

```vb
Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cusName As String = RCReport.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
    Dim id As String = RCReport.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Id: " & id & "\nCustomer Name: " & cusName + "');", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely this is occurring when the control is being constructed.  The usually solution is to test for row count being > 0 : tsaRCReport.Rows.Count > 0;

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where is `tsaRCReport` (in your second code block) referenced in the first code block?   I'm wondering if you're checking the wrong thing.  Disclaimer: It's been about 10 years since I did any ASP so forgive my rustiness.

Comment: @technonaut code is updated

Comment: How are you binding the GridView?

Comment: I'd also debug, and declare ````Dim row as GridViewRow = RCReport.SelectedRow```` and put a breakpoint on that. See if row has any values.  I'm wondering if this is due to you using ````BoundFields```` instead of ````TemplateFields````

Comment: @JohnPete22 I will try that out and see

Comment: @JohnPete22 the GridView already has data using ```Using data As New DataTable() ```

Comment: @JohnPete22 I tried this out ```Dim row as GridViewRow = RCReport.SelectedRow``` but same error

Comment: What does this mean? ```{"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: index"}```

Comment: You're trying to access the ````Row.Cell(1)```` but nothing exists at that Cell point.  Does this GridView get loaded dynamically, like by a button click?

Comment: on page load, the grid is populated by date, there is also a button to get the list if I change the date. all these are working fine. I just want to is select a row and display the selected row item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a quick test for you, to show two different ways you should be able to achieve what you need.

Front-End

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Select Me" SelectImageUrl="~/images/green.png" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

Code-Behind

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Class _testVBNet
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' only setting the value once on initial load.
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim myData As New List(Of SimpleObject)
            Dim obj As SimpleObject = New SimpleObject() With {.Name = "Bob", .City = "New York"}
            myData.Add(obj)
            Dim obj2 As SimpleObject = New SimpleObject() With {.Name = "Aaron", .City = "Denver"}
            myData.Add(obj2)
            Dim obj3 As SimpleObject = New SimpleObject() With {.Name = "Shawn", .City = "Seattle"}
            myData.Add(obj3)

            Me.gvTest.DataSource = myData
            Me.gvTest.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvTest_SelectedIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSelectEventArgs) Handles gvTest.SelectedIndexChanging
        Dim row As GridViewRow = Me.gvTest.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex)
        Dim output As String = String.Format("{0} - {1}", row.Cells(0).Text, row.Cells(1).Text)  ' no .Net error
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvTest_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles gvTest.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim row As GridViewRow = Me.gvTest.SelectedRow
        Dim output As String = String.Format("{0} - {1}", row.Cells(0).Text, row.Cells(1).Text)  ' no .Net error
    End Sub

    Protected Class SimpleObject
        Sub New()
        End Sub
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property City As String
    End Class

End Class
```

Some thoughts:

- EnableViewState = false might be an issue, but *shouldn't be*
- Data dynamically bound via buttons or other events might need to be re-bound, but again it should survive the life trip of the page.

Comment: It worked after removing ```TabContainer TabPanel and ContentTemplate``` thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You not created your index changed event correctly.

You have this:

```
Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

And if you have 2 grids on your web form - which one does above belong to????

Do this:
In the form view designer - click on the grid - display the property sheet. Then click on the lighting bolt (for events), and then double click on the event

[image]

So just like VB6, or even MS-Access? You have to click on the correct event stub. You then get this:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

 End Sub
```

Now how the SelectIndexChanged event IS PREFIXED with the actaul control. I mean, you could have several grids on the web form - which one is your code going to refer to?

Now, in your case, given that the grid view is "gvTest", then double clicking in the index changed event as per above should give you this:

```
 Protected Sub gvTest_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

 End Sub
```

So, now try your code inside of the above event - your cells() collection is empty, since the code stub is wrong, and the index changed event is not firing correctly.

So, after you double click - well if you go back to the property sheet, you see the event name as per this:

[image]

So, either way - the event stub you have is wrong, and thus the index change event is not occurring.